# pip doesn't work for me (I have python 3.9.7 installed) (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, pip

So, I have python 3.9.7 installed.
When I installed it, pip had also been installed.

I checked if python is installed (Windows) using "python --version".
The Problem: When I try the same with pip; "pip --version",
an error occurs saying that **the program can't be executed** (command prompt)

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Is `pip` recognized?

Comment: Try this command: `py -m ensurepip --upgrade`. Ref: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Comment: *The program can't be executed* is not an error message that I would expect to see from `cmd.exe`. At the command prompt do `where pip`. That at least will tell you what the program is that is resulting in the very strange error message.

Comment: I tried "where pip" and it showed me the path. ...Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe.
What should I do now?

Comment: use `py` to run python shell, and use `py --version` to know about the version

Comment: when I entered "py --version" I got "Python 3.9.7"

Answer (score 1):

You can try to reinstall pip. This my solve the issue. Use can either install it over command window with 'py -m ensurepip --upgrade' oder download the 'get-pip.py' file (check https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/).

**Try this first**
Did you added python to PATH? This is also important. Check https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/ to do so

Comment: how can I uninstall pip?

Comment: go to the python folder. in 'Lib/side-packages/' you can find the pip file and delete in manually without using comand window

Comment: when I try to reinstall it (I downloaded get-pip.py) and type "python get-pip.py" I get "ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the python version is the version of your intent.
Windows python installer sometimes defaults to `py` for newer python installations.

```
python --version
```

Then try to install for example `openpyxl` package, with admin access, if required

```
python -m pip install openpyxl
```

Have you already tried `pip3`?

```
pip3 install openpyxl
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It just says "Das angegebene Programm kann nicht ausgeführt werden.", so "The specified program can't be executed" in English.

Comment: What does `where pip` output?

Comment: the path where pip is installed. the end of the path is: "...Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" (I shortened it because of personal information)

Comment: Elevate the rights of the python root folder:  right click-> properties -> security -> edit -> users full control and then could you try again? Just to check on user execution rights.

Comment: So I just entered the path.
Inside the "Scripts" folder are three files:

1. pip.exe
2. pip3.9.exe
3.pip3.exe

When I try to execute them by clicking on the file twice a window appears which tells me that "The file or the directory is damaged or unreadable".

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not on a windows machine to verify my assumptions. Open cmd as admin and run `python -m pip install -U --force pip`

Comment: When I try this, I get:
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Comment: Make sure that `python --version` outputs python 3.9.7. Try also with pip3 instead of pip.

Comment: When I try "pip3" instead of "pip" I get "No module named pip3".

"python --version" shows python 3.9.7 .